# Slow index performance on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2016

I have the following query which runs in 14 seconds (which seems excessive to me):

```
select top 20 App.Id
from
    App
    inner join Base on Base.Id = App.BaseId
WHERE    App.TermId = 1190676
ORDER    BY App.Id
```

apps.Id is a primary key (int). Base.Id is a primary key (int). App.TermId and App.BaseId are a non-clustered indices. App.Term is also a foreign key to a table not used in this query.

The indices on Base.Id, App.BaseId and App.TermId have less than 0.5% fragmentation.

Table Base has 71,879 records, and App has 16,238,898 records. Only 796,661 would be returned by the query above if it hadn't a top condition.

If I remove the inner join, the query runs in less than 1 second.

I don't know much about reading execution plans, but it seems seeking index Base.Id had the highest cost (70%), but was 0.0s. Whereas the clustered index scan was 30% cost but took 18.5 seconds.

I've run:

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE ('dbo.Base', REPAIR_REBUILD)
DBCC CHECKTABLE ('dbo.App', REPAIR_REBUILD)
```

Does 14 seconds sound reasonable? What else might I look into? Is there any other useful info from the execution plan that I can share?

The .sqlPlan can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/UxDvsPRk

**12:52**
I tested with the following and the query above is 1 second slower:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_dbo_App_TermId_BaseId] ON dbo.App
(
    TermId, BaseId
)
```

**1:14**
At a suggestion, I've update the index to be:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_dbo_App_TermId_BaseId] ON dbo.App
(
    TermId, BaseId
)
include (Id)
```

... query is still slow. BUT, now it seems to only be slow when ORDER BY is present. The join itself is less than 1 second.

Comment: Do you want `ANY 20` behavior? Shouldn't your `TOP` be coupled with an `ORDER BY` for predictable output? What does the execution plan look like (please post the .sqlplan to pastetheplan.com, not an image)?

Comment: Without seeing the plans, for this query I would imagine an index on `App (TermId, Id)`  and `Base (Id)` would be the most useful (note the column ordering). You would then get a very fast merge join

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've added the pastebin to my post. I've provided an order by. See: https://pastebin.com/UxDvsPRk

Comment: A better way to share plans is by uploading the plan XML to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). That way, both the graphical plan and XML is easily viewable.

Comment: To clarify that what @Charlieface is saying, you want a compound index, one index that is keyed off of the 2 columns.  He is absolutely correct.   You might be able to fudge that a bit by making App.TermID an included column on the index of App.BaseId, but I would want to test that out to be sure.

Comment: @Charlieface Why TermId and Id? I can remove the ORDER by clause and it's still slow, otherwise App.Id is not used in any join or where clause.

Comment: Sorry `(TermId, BaseId) include (Id)` It's doing a single seek on TermId first that's why

Comment: @Charlieface I added that index, including Id, the query is now 1 second slower at 15 seconds.

Comment: Whereas the query was slow before without the ORDER BY statement, the query now without the ORDER BY is very fast (running in less than a second). But when I put ORDER BY on the query, it goes from < 1 second to 15 seconds.

Comment: That makes sense. If you really need the `order by` maybe better to do `termid, id include (baseid)` and just rely on a hash join

Comment: @Charlieface The thing about the ORDER BY is that this query is driven by jqGrid. So users can click on various columns which determines which column I sort upon

Comment: In that case anything can happen. You cannot satisfy every possible query combination with one index.

Comment: @Charlieface True. :(

Answer (score 0):

Slow indexes can be caused when too many columns are in one index. Look at the table index first to see how many columns live in the index key columns (under the index properties). that could be one issue. The primary key column should never be an unclustered index. Foreign Key should be unclustered. try to update the index on the Base.ID to a clustered index.

Comment: Base.Id is a primary key, it is a clustered index. My foreign key (App.TermId) is a non-clustered index.

Comment: It is ok to have the primary key a non-clustered index when there is a better candidate for the clustered index. It depends on the queries.